# Getting rid of "on behalf of" when sending calendar invites from Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar

My coworker has a problem with Outlook (I believe it's the most recent Outlook.)

He has several email addresses from different companies. When he sends a calendar invite, it shows as "john (john@company1.com) sent on behalf of john (john@company2.com)". He wants that line to go away.

How can we make that line go away?

Comment: Have him send from the correct email account and not from an account he has delegated access to.

Comment: @AthomSfere How do you do that when sending a Calendar invite?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using Exchange Server. Administrators has to enable **Send As** permission for all his AD accounts. Because it looks like for now he has only **Send on Behalf** permission.